# Rails 4: CSS not compiling locally and on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, precompile

So one of the css file is not willing to be precompiled. It totally shows up correct locally, but not when I deployed to heroku. I have no idea how to find a file that is listed blank! No clue how to debug this.

Locally:
[image: Locally]
Heroku http://lightandlovehome.herokuapp.com/

```
$ rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute assets:precompile

I, [2015-11-09T16:21:21.724849 #8701]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/Rex/Desktop/Websites/Projects/lightandlovehome/public/assets/application-b57e39a8d705bcd68793dbb0b14906bde170c536c09e9e26387ca5fb01f19471.css
rake aborted!
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file '' with type 'text/html'
```

The codes: https://github.com/rexfng/lightandlovehome

Comment: Hm... I don't know if this is relevant, but is there any reason why in your application.html.erb you do this:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>? Because you're then including 'application.css' 3 times.

Comment: So I should just write stylesheet_link_tag, 'whateverlink' without 'application'?

Comment: Yes. See: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/stylesheet_link_tag.

Comment: Okay so I took away the repetition. The same error message still occur saying sprockets can't find my blank file with type 'text/HTML'. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error inside of `app/assets/stylesheets/static_pages.css.scss` on line 4.

Try this:

```
@import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round|Oswald:400,300,700');
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. There's a problem with one of my gem file from `polymer-elements-rails`

For future debugger, try to understand how the assets pipeline work, and then go through all your files one by one ;)

Here's a railscast that help me lay the ground work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l0E-D53gEL0

Comment: Ok. But there is (or was at the moment I checked) an error inside of `app/assets/stylesheets/static_pages.css.scss` on line 4.  You are missing colons. Do this: `@import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round|Oswald:400,300,700');`

Comment: lol, I'm exactly looking for it and you just pointed it out! Amazing! Thanks a tonne!

Comment: Your welcome! :) I was posting that as my answer when you answered "Problem solved." I thought really? I'll still post it and you can mark it as correct answer if you'd like show the love.